# I am dead, but I keep things alive

Tags: riddle

> I am dead, but I keep things alive
>   When I'm awake, I light up inside
>   What am I?
>
> You can fit a lot inside.
>   Belongs in a house.

Comment: Hint, please!!!

Comment: You're killing me here. Was my interpretation of the last two lines correct, even if my word wasn't?

Answer (score 24):

Are you a

> refrigerator?

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> A refrigerator does not live, but it keeps groceries fresh.

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> refers to the light inside the fridge which turns on when you open the door.

Comment: I do wonder what a ersev-tngbe(rot13) would look like. :P

Comment: It's a distant cousin of the nyyv-tngbe :P Thanks @Riley for fixing it.

Comment: The first clue seems a bit tenuous. Dead and "Not alive" are not the same thing.

Comment: The second clue as well. I'd say it's awake when it's plugged in, not when it's opened.

Comment: @thecoder16 uggc://pyvpxreurebrf.jvxvn.pbz/jvxv/Ersrev_Wrengbe,_Vpr_Jvmneq

Answer (score 16):

Are you

> compost? (This is not an insult to you)

I am dead

> Compost is made of dead matter

But I keep things alive

> Often to help potted plants grow

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> When the microbes are "awake", they produce heat

You can fit a lot inside

> Compost and soil contains millions of microbes, and tons of NPK (Fertilizer)

I belong in a house

> Many people keep potted plants, or have a separate trash can for compostable materials

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 8):

Are you perhaps

> a fireplace of firewood?

This fits the first hint fairly well:

> The firewood is dead but it heats other things, helping them stay alive.

Lighting up inside is fairly obvious.
The fit isn't perfect, though:

> Arguably the wood is dead but it's the fireplace that lights up inside. Therefore it only seems to make sense if you consider the two together.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer, suspect it's wrong but perhaps on the right track.

Are you

> Chaloth, a type of bread.

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> The yeast in the bread has died during cooking. Bread keeps people alive from calories.

When I'm awake, I light up inside
???

You can fit a lot inside.

> chALOTh. As this clue comes after the 'What am I?', it's not actually an item you can fit a lot inside, it's a word that can fit the four letters 'alot' inside,

Belongs in a house

> Similar sot of logic. Insert the answer somewhere amongst the letters 'ahouse' to make a new word.

Comment: Also you usually don't keep this sort of thing outside, so it would indeed belong in a house ;)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are

> An aquarium type fish tank?

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> The tank is just glass, an air pump etc. but the creatures inside would die without it

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> The tanks normally have colourful lighting

You can fit a lot inside.

> The tank is hollow and takes up a lot of space

Belongs in a house.

> People who like fish might have one or more of these in their houses. They're not exactly portable

Answer (score 3):

You are a

> Power bank

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> discharges itself to keep my phone powered.

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> awake refers to being charged... with electrons... which could generate light...?

You can fit a lot inside.

> a power bank could store a lot of mAh, sometimes multiple charges to a phone.

Belongs in a house

> power bank protector case cover acts as the house.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you are

> a volcano

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> It's technically asleep, so it can be dead as well ? It keeps things alive with warmth, and volcano are often very fertile areas (so they maintain crops alive)

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> Obvious

What am I?

> A volcano, then

You can fit a lot inside.

> Volcanoes are big and hollow, so as long as you don't mind lava...

Belongs in a house.

> ... lava lamps ?

Comment: Lava lamps do not house an entire volcano, though.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> an oven

I am dead but I keep things alive

> An oven is an inanimate object so its dead .It is used to cook food and hence keeps things alive

When I am awake ,I light up inside

> It lights up when you use it

You can fit a lot inside

> Self explanatory

Belongs in a house

> Obviously ! In a Kitchen!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are a

> TV and/or Food

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> TV is dead though I can't live without it, and food is basically dead, but recently dead i.e. fresh.

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> When a TV is switched on the screen is illuminated from inside,  and when food is cooked it wakes up and becomes tasty and digestible

You can fit a lot inside.

> On TV? A lot of s**t, but food, you can fit a lot of that inside

Belongs in a house.

> TV belongs in a house or a public house (a bar), a house of ill repute, etc. And food belongs in a house, in the kitchen

Comment: Dead vs. inanimate...

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be

> a lighthouse

Rationale:

> Keeps sailors alive.  Lights up inside when active.  Don't know about the lot - perhaps a pun in English?  A lighthouse belongs in a house.

Answer (score 0):

You might be a

> Microwave

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> You use radioactive (alive?) heating to keep things 'alive'.

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> When you are on, the light goes on inside.

You can fit a lot inside.

> A lot of stuff can fit inside a microwave, ask [Mr. Bean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFlpiafC2-c)

Belongs in a house.

> A microwave is usually in someone's kitchen, which is in his/her house.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are a

> Fire Alarm

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> It's an inanimate object but people are saved when it goes off!

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> When it is activated, there is usually a light that goes off

You can fit a lot inside.

> Not so much, unless you're talking about sound

Belongs in a house.

> They are usually in houses

Answer (score 0):

You are a

> switch

Explanation:

> You are dead(off) normally.
>
>  You keep things not destroyed from overvoltage.
>
>  When you are awake(on), you light up inside by light.

Comment: @F1Krazy, Thanks. You don't think 'switch' is right?

Comment: I'm not convinced, to be honest, but it's not up to me. Only Sploash knows what the intended answer is. I added the spoiler tags in just because that's the accepted practice for all answers here, not because I think it's wrong. Welcome to Puzzling.SE, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

You are a

> lamp

I am dead, but I keep things alive

> Normally you are turned off
>  If you turned on, it means it is midday and every things are alive not sleepy.

When I'm awake, I light up inside

> When you turned on, you light up inside.